# Command not found message

Tags: shell, command, command-not-found

When running invalid commands without any parameters or options, in my experience we get only two kinds of messages which are exemplified below:

```
~$ Date
No command 'Date' found, did you mean:
 Command 'yate' from package 'yate' (universe)
 Command 'date' from package 'coreutils' (main)
 Command 'late' from package 'late' (universe)
 Command 'kate' from package 'kate' (universe)
Date: command not found
~$ fjldjflsk
fjldjflsk: command not found
~$
```

I'm interested in knowing more about how this works. Specifically, when can I know which of these two kinds of messages I'm going to get prior to running the command? Is there some kind of environment variable or any other device that would allow me to alter this behavior easily? I'd like to get only the second kind of message.

Comment: You are on Linux. Which variant? You want to remove the predictions?

Comment: @Kusalananda Actually the code above was ran in WSL - Ubuntu, but I'd like to know how to deal with this in regular Ubuntu. If it matters the shell is Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bash` shell calls a function called `command_not_found_handle` whenever a command is not found.

This function can be viewed with `declare -f command_not_found_handle` and may look something like this (found on an Ubuntu system):

```
command_not_found_handle ()
{
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

As you can see, it use another tools called `command-not-found`. It also uses unquoted variable expansions and unnecessary `return` statements, but that's beside the point at the moment.

To remove the predictions that this function makes, you can either remove this function altogether using

```
unset -f command_not_found_handle
```

(this is probably the best option) or, you can uninstall the executable that the function uses, assuming a system using `apt`:

```
sudo apt purge command-not-found
```

(the `command-not-found` command is part of the package of the same name on e.g. Ubuntu at least).

For more information about the `command_not_found_handle` function, see the `bash` manual.

Comment: Hmm, I just did the unset command and ran the same command only with set instead of unset, but didn't retrieve the functionality. Do I see to restart my shell? (I'd rather not at the moment).

Comment: @command_not_found You could try `source /etc/bash.bashrc` (or whatever the equivalent file is called on your system).  On the Ubuntu machine I have access to, that file sets up the `command_not_found_handle` function.

Comment: It does not have to be a Linux, to run apt (E.g. Ubuntu on WSL).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Never said so either.

Comment: “…you can uninstall the executable that the function uses, assuming a Linux using apt”: It does not have to be a Linux, to run apt (E.g. Ubuntu on WSL).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Sure I'll change it (you could have done too).