# bash/zsh hook - Add to PATH only if no matching file found

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, node.js, npm

I am looking for a bash/zsh *hook*, that is invoked when a command is not found.

Say I run some arbitrary executable:

```
xyz foo --bar
```

1. say that bash/zsh cannot find the executable.
2. is there a way to handle "not found" and then load some libraries to the PATH dynamically after that?

something like this:

```
function xyz {
  if ! test -f xyz; then
     load_libs xyz
  fi
  command -v xyz;
}
```

something like this function, but it would be for unknown executables.

So generically it would look something like:

```
function on_not_found {
  if ! test -f "$1"; then
     load_libs "$1"
  fi
  command -v "$@";
}
```

Comment: bash has `command_not_found_handle` and zsh `command_not_found_handler` - some discussion here [Command not found message](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501245/command-not-found-message)

Comment: ok cool, is there a way to override that function somehow? seems worthy of an answer not a comment to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `zsh` and `bash` have hook functions that you can define to handle cases where a command is not found. It's called `command_not_found_handle` in `bash` and `command_not_found_handler` in `zsh` ([inspired by `bash`'s but with the typo/misnomer fixed](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2007/msg00592.html)).

Note however that they run in a child process (not to mention that the command could be not-found by a subshell), so cannot make changes to your shell environment.

You could do:

### zsh

```
command_not_found_handler() {
  {
    if (( ! IN_CNFH++)) && load_lib "$1"; then
      "$@"
    else
      print -ru2 -- "$functrace[1]: command not found: $1"
      return 127
    fi
  } always {
    (( IN_CNFH-- ))
  }
}
```

The `IN_CNFH` parts to avoid infinite recursion if the command still can't be found after `load_lib` succeeded.

If you already have a `command_not_found_handler` (some systems provide one in their zsh default configuration to suggest names of packages to install when  a command is not found), you could insert that before it with something like:

```
functions[command_not_found_handler]='
  {
    if (( ! IN_CNFH++)) && load_lib "$1"; then
      "$@"
      return
    fi
  } always {
    (( IN_CNFH-- ))
  }
  '$functions[command_not_found_handler]
```

### bash

The equivalent in bash would look like:

```
command_not_found_handle() {
  local ret
  if (( ! IN_CNFH++)) && load_lib "$1"; then
    "$@"
    ret=$?
  else
    printf >&2 '%s\n' "$BASH_ARGV0: $1: command not found: $1"
    ret=127
  fi
  (( IN_CNFH-- ))
  return "$ret"
}
```

Or the incremental variant in case there's already a `command_not_found_handle`:

```
eval 'command_not_found_handle() {
  local ret
  if (( ! IN_CNFH++)) && load_lib "$1"; then
    "$@"
    ret=$?
    (( IN_CNFH-- ))
    return "$ret"
  fi
  (( IN_CNFH-- ))
  '"$(typeset -f command_not_found_handle | tail -n +2)"'
}'
```

Comment: Is there a way to rename the original function (or alias it) and call the original function from a custom one? could get a toString on the original and then call that maybe?

Comment: @AlexanderMills,see my answer at your follow-up question: [How to alias a function and call from function with original name](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/691535)